# Is there a way to modify eigen slice?

Tags: c++11, eigen3

I have an `Eigen::Matrix<double, M, N> matrix;` and I have a function that needs only a 3x3 slice and modifies it

```
void ModifyBlock(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> & block){
   // A stupid example
   block += Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>::Identity();
}
```

Passing a slice of the original matrix is not possible as the following code fails to compile:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const int M = 10;
    const int N = 20;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, M, N> matrix;
    // Initialize matrix
    ModifyBlock(matrix(vector<int>{1,3,7}, vector<int>{0,2,4});
    return 0;    
}

cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>
```

I wonder if there is a way to do this.

In the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) I could not find a mention of that the slices are necessarily constant references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that slices are not writable, but you can't convert them to lvalue references of `Eigen::Matrix`. With C++11 you can simply pass them as rvalue reference template:

```
template<class Derived>
void ModifyBlock(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> && block){
   // A stupid example
   block += Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>::Identity();
}
```